# Корректный ресайз WindowChrome

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Столкнулся с проблемой.
В общем, использую WindowChrome для своего окна:

```
<Window
x:Class="CustomWindow.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomWindow"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="525"
Height="350"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome
        CaptionHeight="31"
        ResizeBorderThickness="3"
        UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
<Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="maxminbtn"
        Height="83"
        Margin="432,10,10,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Content="Button" />
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Image 1]
И при ресайзе окна, оно вылазит за рамки монитора. (Видно по черному бордеру) Как это пофиксить ? 
Пол интернета перекопал, но ничего годного не нашёл.
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Никак. Когда окно развернуто, его граница не отображается. Хотите ее отображать - выводите внутри окна. Хотя, зачем она нужна когда окно развернуто?

Comment: Насколько я знаю когда окно развернуто не отображается граница "Не клиентской области" (Non client area). А здешь же выходит так что имеенно "Клиентская область" (Client area) выходит за рамки монитора.
Вроде так, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Хром и есть неклиентская область

Comment: Хорошо, тогда есть вариант решения что бы оно так сильно не выходило за рамки монитора? Ибо часть содержимого может быть не видна.

Comment: Размещайте внутри клиентской области